# How do i create a new codemirror mode?

Tags: javascript, tokenize, codemirror, codemirror-modes

So i recently finished my own functional programming language for a project and I want to create a codemirror mode for the language as it transcompiles to javascript. I have written a tokenizer for it but I can't understand the way codemirror structures their tokenizers. This is the the basic structure of the language:

```
<FUNCTION>(<ARGUMENT 1>, <ARGUMENT 2>....)

nested functions:

<FUNCTION 1>(<FUNCTION 2>(<ARGUEMNT 1>), <ARGUMENT 1>....)

series of functions:

<FUNCTION>(<ARGUMENT 1>, <ARGUMENT 2>...), <FUNCTION>()

strings:

`this is a string`

comments:

;this is a comment;
```

So the only forms it has are functions, arguments, commas, strings, and comments.

This is what I have for the mode so far:

```
(function(mod) {
  if (typeof exports == "object" && typeof module == "object") // CommonJS
    mod(require("../../lib/codemirror"));
  else if (typeof define == "function" && define.amd) // AMD
    define(["../../lib/codemirror"], mod);
  else // Plain browser env
    mod(CodeMirror);
})(function(CodeMirror) {
"use strict";

CodeMirror.defineMode("diff", function() {

  var TOKEN_NAMES = {
    '(': 'positive',
    ')': 'negative',
    ',': 'comma',
    ';': 'comment',
    '`': 'strings', 
  };

  return {
    token: function(stream) {
      var tw_pos = stream.string.search(/[\t ]+?$/);

      if (!stream.sol() || tw_pos === 0) {
        stream.skipToEnd();
        return ("error " + (
          TOKEN_NAMES[stream.string.charAt(0)] || '')).replace(/ $/, '');
      }

      var token_name = TOKEN_NAMES[stream.peek()] || stream.skipToEnd();

      if (tw_pos === -1) {
        stream.skipToEnd();
      } else {
        stream.pos = tw_pos;
      }

      return token_name;
    }
  };
});

CodeMirror.defineMIME("text/x-mylang", "mylang");

});
```

It's not working so far. If anyone can point me in the right direction or show how a mode for a language like this would work that would be of great help.